# Blank screen after installing nvidia graphic card on ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04

I am using ubuntu 22.04 lts.

I installed an Nvidia graphics card, Nvidia gforce gtx 1650 mobile, and rebooted it. After reboot, it showed an option to enroll kernel and I enrolled it but after that when I rebooted it, it's stuck with a blank screen. someone help me..

[image: screen image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1453844/edit) your question and add more details of what the graphics card is and what video drivers you installed?  Please give us as much detail of your situation you can.  Without details we can only guess.  Thank you!

Comment: Im stuck at the blanck screen and tty not working I don't know why and i can't shut down my laptop because my laptop doesn't give the option to shut down with the power key

Comment: What driver did you install?  Please be precise as there are a couple of different available drivers.  If you installed like the `nvidia-driver-525-open` it will not work with your graphics card.  The standard `nvidia-driver-525` should work fine with your video card.  Also, did you disable secure boot in your BIOS?